# Lookup person by name in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

Im wondering what the poor mans solution to implementing a search across your person/account record set, partially matching on name? Happy to adjust the table, or create others if needed.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  uuid timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
  created bigint,
  email text,
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  password text
)
```

I'd rather not have to add lucene or some other technology just to solve this particular problem.

In case its at all relevant. Im using java with the datastax driver.

Answer (score 1):

@jacob

I've implemented name searching a while ago. First I use a Lucene standard analyzer to split names into token. Then foreach token I index it.

Tokennizer code is **[here](https://github.com/doanduyhai/XKE-Achilles/blob/Solution/src/main/java/info/archinnov/achilles/demo/music/utils/LuceneUtils.java)** , pretty simple

For the design in Cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE search_index 
(
   search_type text, // type of search, can be 'FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME' or 'EMAIL'
   value text, // indexed valued of firstname, lastname or email
   user_id bigint, // id of user having the searched firstname, lastname or email
   PRIMARY_KEY(search_type,value)
);
```

Search on firstname starting with **'Jo'**:

```
SELECT * FROM search_index WHERE search_type='FIRSTNAME' AND value>='Jo' AND value<'Jo'+'b\uFFFF'
```

**'b\uFFFF'** represents the last character in UTF-8 enconding. With such a query you will be able to find all firstname starting with **'Jo'**.  It can be **'John'**, **'Johnny'**, **'Josh',**... until **'Jo'+'b\uFFFF'**

For search on lastname or email, it's exactly the same technique.

Please note that with **Cassandra** you can only do a search by **exact string match** or **start with** semantic. It is not possible to search using **contain** semantic with a simple design.